# Python test validation and reporting

Tags: library, python, software-testing

I have a Python testing framework that uses external data to create tests. Based on the data sent, a test is created with any required dependencies (rest api, queues, etc.)and then uses the provided data to retrieve the results.

The issue I am having is finding a good library to verify the actual with the expected and then give the results. I would like to use something like pytest but I have had trouble trying to get it to work with external data and it takes over control flow. The closest I have found to what I am trying to achieve with actual/expected is pyassert https://pypi.org/project/pyassert/ - but based on updates, this doesn't seem like a great option.

I'm hoping to find an existing library that can be fulfill this functionality, or know if writing my own is the best option.

Comment: If anyone comes along with a similar question, my solve was to build a pytest plugin that gave me the functionality I was looking for.